# What would be the most common one word or phrase to describe the name of a group that people work in a business organization?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I work in a research institute where we have operation groups called in many different names such as *Office, Branch Office, Group, Unit, Center, Division, Department, Project Team, Section*, etc.

I'm now drafting a kind of questionnaire asking everyone in the organization to answer it, and one of the entry items included in it is "Your xxxxxx: ___________."

In the blank, I would like the answers to write the name of the group they belong to, and what I'm looking for is a word or phrase that could best fit in the "xxxxxx" part. Is there any such one word or phrase? One of my colleagues has suggested "Affiliation." Do you agree?

Comment: This is going to be highly dependent on the jargon of your particular workplace.  In mine, for example, "Affiliation?" would definitely mean, "Which labor union (if any) do you belong to?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably isn't a single word or phrase that will capture all of these without any ambiguity or confusion. You might want to include some examples in your questionnaire along with that question.

"**Organizational Unit**" is used in a similar setting to address the problem you are describing. More info & examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_unit_(computing)